# Unbound breakpoints while debugging TypeScript VS Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, nestjs

I am using VS Code on my Ubuntu machine to debug a `Nest.js` `TypeScript` project. Some of my breakpoints are unbound and does not get hit at all. I have played a lot with `launch.json`. Indeed, I have tried several `launch.json` and `tsconfig.json` files. Also used auto attach feature. However, some of my breakpoints are not bound.

It seems that my not bound breakpoints is related to something other than `launch.json`. Anyone can help me please?

Note 1: `Nest.js` is a framework based on `TypeScript` and `Node.js`.
Note 2: I have a similar project on my machine which can be debugged very fine. So my machine is able to do the debug in general. Consider that settings on both projects are same.

Comment: Hey @Afshar did you find the solution to this problem? I would really appreciate your help. I am sill stuck on the same issue.

Comment: @HarshGupta Unfortunately, I cannot remember if that problem get solved or not. It's a little bit old.

Answer (score -6):

In vsCode:
go to preferences => settings =>
search 'breakpoints' =>
check 'Allow Breakpoints Everywhere'